# Why ajax calling for search doesn't display output?

Tags: ajax, search, laravel-5

I had search field using ajax call in laravel 5. It search in Db and display output in table. When user click on the page, it should display all db query. When user type in search field it should display the output according to the search input.

This is the controller for searching:

```
  function action(Request $request)
{
     if($request->ajax())
     {
          $output = '';
          $query = $request->get('query');
          if($query != '')
            {
               $data = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                        ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                        ->paginate(10);

            }
            else
            {
               $data = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                        ->paginate(10);
              }

          $total_row = $data->count();

          if($total_row > 0)
          {
               foreach($data as $row)
               {
                $output .= '
                <tr>
                 <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->seksyen_kecil.'</td>
                 <td>'.$row->nobadan.'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
           }
          }
          else
          {
           $output = '
           <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
           </tr>
           ';
          }
          $data = array(
           'table_data'  => $output,
           'total_data'  => $total_row
          );

      echo json_encode($data);
     }
}
```

This is the view blade displaying the output:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search"></input>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Senarai Kakitangan</div>
                     <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (session('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ session('status') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif


                             @if(Auth::check())
                                <div class="container table-responsive col-lg-12">
                                    <!-- <div class="container text-center"> -->      
                                      <h3 align="center">Total Data : <span id="total_records"></span></h3>

                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td><strong>#</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-1"><strong>Nama</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-3"><strong>Seksyen</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg3-2"><strong>No Badan</strong></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        <tbody>

                                        </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    <!-- </div> -->
                                    <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                                        {{ $itemregistrations->links() }}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            @if(Auth::guest())
                                <a href="/login" class="btn btn-info"> Anda perlu log masuk.</a>
                            @endif
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

The javascript for searching:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

fetch_profil_data();

function fetch_profil_data(query = '')
{
  $.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
  method:'GET',
  data:{query:query},
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data)
{
  $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
  $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
}
})
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
 var query = $(this).val();
fetch_profil_data(query);
});
});
</script>
```

The route for the search is:

```
 Route::get('/profil/action', 'Modul\ProfilController@action')->name('live_search.action');
```

I couldn't find any error and console.log also doesn't produce any output..

The searching doesn't work and don't display any result.

The script link i put in app.blade.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the error in log

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hre1m\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hre1m\\public\\index.php(53): 
Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\hre1m\\server.php(21): 
require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
 #52 {main}
 "}
```

Comment: What laravel version are you using? In your jquery, did you pass the **headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }**

Comment: laravel 5...i don't pass the token..sorry, qutie new to ajax. where is should put it?

Comment: I follow this tutorial for search field.. https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/live-search-in-laravel-using-ajax.html

Comment: Did you checked if it goes to the controller function `action` by `dd($request->all())` ? And is it working without search?

Comment: where to put dd($request->all()) to check it? in controller?

Comment: yes in your controller function `action` before line `if($request->ajax())`

Comment: my assumption it looks like not invoke the ajax call

Comment: i already put in controller...it doesn't affect anything..

Comment: yes that means it doesnt go into the function.  check in your console network tab OR check in laravel logs for error

Comment: can you try clearing `laravel.log` file and then try to run your code and then see what error is showing

Comment: it doesn't produce anything...after cleaned and run

Comment: can you check by `alert(data.table_data)` within `success:function(data)`

Comment: still nothing appear..like it doesn't invoke ajax call